# Gracefully shut down Flink Kafka Comsumer at run time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am using FlinkKafkaConsumer010 with Flink 1.2.0, and the problem I am facing is that: Is there a way that I can shut down the entire pipeline **programmatically** if some scenario is seen?

On possible solution is that I can shut down the kafka consumer source by calling the *close()* method defined inside of FlinkKafkaConsumer010, then the pipeline with shut down as well. For this approach, I create a list that contains the references to all FlinkKafkaConsumer010 instance that I created at the beginning of the pipeline for the kafka topics. Then during the execution of the pipeline, I have another thread that calls *close()* of each of the FlinkKafkaConsumer010 in my list. I expect that this should shut down the consumer, but the result is that the consumer is still running.

Can someone shed some light on this or give me some other suggestion on how can I shut down the flink pipeline at runtime programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

Is the scenario that you're trying to respond to based on the input events? If so, I would suggest to have a MapFunction somewhere appropriate in the pipeline, and just deliberately throw an exception to fail the job when some condition is met.

The other alternative is to look at the `isEndOfStream` method in `KeyedDeserializationSchema`. Basically, when the condition is met for some event, signal that the stream has ended.

One other option to consider is to let the MapFunction mentioned above be instead a FlatMapFunction, that send an signaling event to the outside world. A separate process external to the Flink job listens to that event, and when received, shutdown the Flink job via the Flink CLI.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I think the first approach might meet my need. But I met a problem that when I throw an exception in another thread, I can see in the debugger that the exception is caught, but Flink doesn't restart based on that. Can you please give some help on how to let Flink restart the pipeline? (I already set Restart_Strategy )

Comment: Added: The scenario is not based on the input of events, but based on the change of kafka topics. More specifically, there might be new topics added to kafka but once the pipeline starts, it is unable to detect this. What I am trying to do is I want to create a another thread that keeps monitoring if there is a new kafka topic created. If so, then I restart the pipeline.

Comment: Regarding the exception throwing: did you from it directly from the MapFunction's map method? That should fail the job and stop the pipeline.

Comment: Also, upcoming in Flink 1.4 there will be topic / partition discovery feature added to the Flink cosumer, so you wouldn't need to do this in Flink 1.4. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-4022.

Comment: It's glad to know that Flink 1.4 will support this, but from what I see Flink 1.4 will be released in Sep this year. As far as for this piece of functionality, is there any plan to speed things up?