# Stop Flink Kafka consumer task programmatically

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I'm using Kafka consumer with Flink 1.9 (in Scala 2.12), and facing the following problem (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165747)): the consumer should stop fetching data (and finish the task) when no new messages are received for a specific amount of time (since the stream is potentially infinite, so there is no "end-of-stream" message in the topic itself).

I've tried to use `ProcessFunction` which calls `consumer.close()`, but this did not help (consumer continues to run). Throwing an exception in `ProcessFunction` kills the job completely, which is not what I want (since the job consists of several stages, which are canceled after throwing an exception). Here is my ProcessFunction:

```scala
class TimeOutFunction( // delay after which an alert flag is thrown
  val timeOut: Long, consumer: FlinkKafkaConsumer[Row]
) extends ProcessFunction[Row, Row] {
  // state to remember the last timer set
  private var lastTimer: ValueState[Long] = _

  override def open(conf: Configuration): Unit = { // setup timer state
    val lastTimerDesc = new ValueStateDescriptor[Long]("lastTimer", classOf[Long])
    lastTimer = getRuntimeContext.getState(lastTimerDesc)
  }

  override def processElement(value: Row, ctx: ProcessFunction[Row, Row]#Context, out: Collector[Row]): Unit = { // get current time and compute timeout time
    val currentTime = ctx.timerService.currentProcessingTime
    val timeoutTime = currentTime + timeOut
    // register timer for timeout time
    ctx.timerService.registerProcessingTimeTimer(timeoutTime)
    // remember timeout time
    lastTimer.update(timeoutTime)
    // throughput the event
    out.collect(value)
  }

  override def onTimer(timestamp: Long, ctx: ProcessFunction[Row, Row]#OnTimerContext, out: Collector[Row]): Unit = {
    // check if this was the last timer we registered
    if (timestamp == lastTimer.value) {
      // it was, so no data was received afterwards.
      // stop the consumer.
      consumer.close()
    }
  }
}
```

The `isEndOfStream()` method on a deserialization schema is also no good, since it requires `nextElement` (and my case is kind of vice-versa, since the stream should stop when there is no next element for some time).

So, there is a way to do this (preferably without subclassing `FlinkKafkaConsumer` and/or using reflection)?

Comment: Do you just want to stop the consumer or the entire job?

Comment: @TobiSH Only the consumer.

Comment: I can't think of any flink specific solution for that. What you can of course do is to consume a 2nd topic with some control messages (like "stop consumer"). In your process function you could emit such a message. This pattern is described in a more detailed way here: https://mux.com/blog/using-control-streams-to-manage-apache-flink-applications/

Comment: Could you please elaborate why you wanna shut down the consumer?

Comment: @TobiSH That's because the next step of the job processes chunks of data, and it triggers only upon reaching either a specified number of events in the buffer or the end of the source. In Kafka, that may never occur, so it was decided to stop consuming on timeout.

Comment: do you think that a window might be an option?

Comment: @TobiSH Probably yes, for now I'm using a window which is 1 event wide (so the data are immediately sent to the next step, without any chunking). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280077) is the similar question independently written by my colleague, he provided a link to the full code (we're working on an open-source project).